# How to clear empty keys in a dictionary with subdictionaries

Tags: python, regex, string, escaping, substring

I have up to now the following regex in python:

```
 (\"[^"]+":\s)({}|\[\]|null)(,?\s?)
```

I need to match all the occurrences of "some key": [] or {} or null from a string, but I need to exclude the cases where "some key" is "Note", a case string is:

```
test= {'merda 1': {},
         'merda 2': [1,2,3],
         1: """"só pra fude""",
         'Note': "foda-se",
         'Não reclama': [],
         'Tédio da nisso': OrderedDict({'Note': None, 1:2}),
         'None':None,
         'Quero $$$': (),
         'Note': [],
         12.2: None,
         666: OrderedDict(),
         'Fudeu': OrderedDict({1:None, 2:1, 3:2})
         }

string_json = json.dumps(test)
```

The intention is to filter the empty leafs of the dictionary, but I need to keep the OrderedDicts present in it.

**SOLUTION:**
Based in Martin answer:

```
def clean_dict(dictobj):
    """ Clean any number of empty leafs of a dictionary
    """
    def del_empty_value(dictobj):
        """ Delete empty values recursively
        """
        for key, value in dictobj.items():
            if not (value or key == 'Note'):
                del dictobj[key]
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                del_empty_value(value)
    from json import dumps
    initial_hash = len(dumps(dictobj))
    while True:
        del_empty_value(dictobj)
        new_hash = len(dumps(dictobj))
        if new_hash == initial_hash:
            break
        initial_hash = new_hash
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_occurrences of "some text"_"? What exactly do you want matched in the example string?

Comment: When you match with regex, you want to remove it or keep it? This part is not clear to me.

Comment: Martin, I want to remove it. Edited to make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you let a json parser do all the hard work for you?

```
import json

s = '{"1": "\\"s\\u00f3 pra fude", "None": null, "Note": [], "N\\u00e3o reclama": [], "12.2": null, "666": {}, "merda 2": [1, 2, 3], "merda 1": {}, "T\\u00e9dio da nisso": {"Note": null}, "Fudeu": {"1": null, "2": 1, "3": 2}, "Quero $$$": []}'

d = json.loads(s)
result = dict((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if not v or k == "Note")
```

The last line filters out any key:value pairing where `bool(v)` is not `False` (`[]`, `{}` and `None` all satisfy this criteria) OR where key value is not "Note".

Result:

```
{u'12.2': None,
 u'666': {},
 u'None': None,
 u'Note': [],
 u'N\xe3o reclama': [],
 u'Quero $$$': [],
 u'merda 1': {}}
```

**EDIT:**

Since the question as been updated, there's a better answer:

```
 test= {'merda 1': {},
     'merda 2': [1,2,3],
     1: """"só pra fude""",
     'Note': "foda-se",
     'Não reclama': [],
     'Tédio da nisso': OrderedDict({'Note': None, 1:2}),
     'None':None,
     'Quero $$$': (),
     'Note': [],
     12.2: None,
     666: OrderedDict(),
     'Fudeu': OrderedDict({1:None, 2:1, 3:2})
     }

def delete_empty_value(test):
    for k, v in test.items():
        if not (v or type(k) is OrderedDict or k == 'Note'):
            del test[k]
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            delete_empty_value(v)
```

This new filter keeps any key:value pair where:

1. The value is not `[]`, `{}` or `None`
2. The value is an instance of OrderedDict
3. The key == "Note"

Comment: This is nice, but I have a problem that some items are OrderedDict, I changed the question to reflect it

Comment: Martin, I have subdictionaries (like 'Tádio da nisso') where the filter do not work.. maybe if I do this recursively

Comment: Updated recursively - I'm still not `100%` on the requirements but this should be very close. What about "Tedio da nisso"? You wanted to keep anything with "Note" as key no?